# Moderator elections with two candidates look funny

Tags: bug, status-declined, election

There are two candidates in the [Food & Cooking Moderator Elections](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election). There are still buttons for three choices. Since it's single transferable vote, you don't actually need the second or third choices, but this isn't terribly obvious from the page, given that the buttons are still there, and the help on the side says you have three votes.

Mostly this is just a little ugly, but it might be more friendly if it dealt with it, especially for any relatively new users voting in their first moderator election!

Comment: The same is true of the [Photograhy election](http://photo.stackexchange.com/election)

Comment: The third is for the write-in candidate. I'm voting for Alton Brown.

Comment: Yes, it does look funny, but I disagree *that's* the problem.  The problem here is there are only 2 candidates.

Comment: @NickCraver: Perhaps so. But it might be unrealistic to expect it never to happen.

Comment: This isn't causing a problem per-se. We are not going to invest time in "fixing" something that we don't think of as broken.

Comment: @Oded For what it's worth, it's a bit frustrating to be told "this isn't a problem at all" when to users on my site it was definitely noticeably slightly broken. But I totally agree with you declining this (it's very low priority/severity, and I know you have more important things to do). Would've understood if you'd said that.